# Translating a working Curl - Form POST into PS Core

Tags: powershell, curl, translate

Using PS 7.2.6, upload a CSV

curl version works every time:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:5224/api/mail/bb2xml' -F 'Attachments=@"C:\temp\SampleCsv\atsample.csv"'
```

> Result 200: Task completed successfully

I'd like to implement using invoke-RestMethod.

```
$Form = @{Attachments=(get-item -path "C:\bbas\MRVapp\CSV\atsample.csv")}; Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Form $Form
```

> Invoke-RestMethod: Result 400: The process cannot access the file
> 'C:\bbas\MRVapp\CSV\atsample.csv' because it is being used by another
> process.

How do I get this operational in PS?

TY in advance!

Comment: Start by making sure no other process has an exclusive lock on the file. Are you generating/modifying the CSV in question in the same script? If yes, please show the whole script

Comment: I think you want ```Get-Content``` rather than ```Get-Item``` - the curl command sends the *contents* of the file, where as your powershell sends metadata about the file.

Comment: Mathias - I previously checked handles to ensure nothing is open.  AgaIn the Curl command works flawlessly - regardless if the CSV is open for editing or not.

Comment: McLayton - 
I tried replacing get-item with get-Content. 

Invoke-RestMethod: Result 400: Bad Number of Attachments - 0

Comment: @mclayton, at least according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest#example-6-simplified-multipart-form-data-submission), `Get-Item` is the right command: "" If a `System.IO.FileInfo` value is present, the file contents are submitted."

Comment: While finding the correct PowerShell-native solution is definitely desirable, a stopgap could be to simply stick with `curl` (`curl.exe` now ships with Windows). Note that up to at lest 7.2.x you'll have to ``\``-escape the embedded `"` chars., though, due to a long-standing bug.

Comment: Thanks for diving in to help solve this one folks.  This is one I have walked away from and come back.  Nada yet.

Comment: McLement0 - Yes - that thinking is what I walked away with a few weeks ago.  The Curl just "works". 
--Mathias that is the whole script.